# i need check if one note is under 95 with function

Tags: function, plsql

i need to created a function where i return true if all the note of a student in a session is over 94 so 95 and more

its on plsql oracle. 
i try so many thing please help me

```
create or replace function BonnePerformance (CodeP in char, CodeS in char)
return boolean is
declare 
    noteMauvaise integer;
begin
    select Min(note) into noteMauvaise
    from Inscription 
    where codePermanent = CodeP and codeSession = CodeS ;
    if  noteMauvaise < 95 then
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    end if;
end;
/
```

if this function on the student is true i add it too a list a good student and print it.

sorry for my english im french

Comment: OK, nice. But what's the question?

Comment: the function did not compile

Answer (score 0):

Compilation error is due to `declare` keyword. No need to use `declare` inside the function. Please try the below code. Hope this works fine.

```
create or replace function BonnePerformance (CodeP in char, CodeS in char)
return boolean is
    noteMauvaise integer;
begin
    select Min(note) into noteMauvaise
    from Inscription 
    where codePermanent = CodeP and codeSession = CodeS ;
    if  noteMauvaise < 95 then
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    end if;
end;
/
```